# Where is the start up file located?

Tags: startup, input-devices

I want to add some lines which should execute every time Ubuntu boots up, so I don't have to change them manually everytime. I've read in some place that you should edit this file `/etc/rc.local`. However when I add the lines I want to execute at start up it doesn't run those lines.

So I wonder where the start up file is located in ubuntu?
Those lines I want to add is to change the sensitivity for the trackpoint

One of the lines I want to add:
`echo -n 250 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity`

Comment: Similar question you might love to have a look at: [How to run scripts on start up of ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up-of-ubuntu)

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up-of-ubuntu

Comment: Also have a look at [RcLocalHowto: Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working fine here. Have you made sure that `/etc/rc.local` ends with "exit 0":

```
...stuff...

# set trackpoint sensitivity
echo -n 250 > /sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/sensitivity

exit 0
```

If it does, you're maybe using the wrong path. Try `/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/sensitivity` instead.

Comment: @htorque - The problem now it seems the file isn't run at boot up. Instead I have to run it manually with `sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start`. Then the trackpointer start to be more responsive. Do you possible know some reason why `rc.local` isn't executed automatically?

Comment: @starcorn: I'd first test, if it really isn't called during boot. Edit the file to just contain "touch /home/YOURUSER/Desktop/rclocal" and the "exit 0". Then reboot - if you find the file "rclocal" on your desktop, then the script was run and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @htorque- I have tried adding `touch...` to the rc.local file now, and the file ends with `exit 0`. After the reboot the file didn't appear on the desktop. But it will appear if I run the script manually. Where can the problem else be? :(

Comment: Do you have the files `/etc/rc*.d/S99rc.local` where * is 2-5?

Comment: Yes I have that file in `rc*.d` 2-5

Comment: Okay, if you also have `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`, `/etc/init.d/rcS`, and `/etc/init.d/rc` I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: is it `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` or is it `/etc/init.d/rc-sysinit.conf` ? either case i dont have that file, but the other two is there

Comment: Oh, great: now do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall upstart` and you should have the file `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`.